# Python BaseHTTP gets struck while starting nginx or other services

Tags: python

I am using BaseHTTP since its very simple. Please advice if I'm using it wrong.

```
if self.path.endswith("nginxstart"):
    xxxxxx 
    status=os.system("/home/karthik/nginx/nginx-1.0.4/sbin/nginx");  #tried ls -l and works
    self.wfile.write("nginx restarted")
```

nginx gets started but doesn't write "nginx restarted" to browser until I kill the python server.
When I do netstat -anp | grep 'nginx's pid' there are two listening ports :

1. python server was listening  (port 8000: which I have killed)
2. on which nginx was supposed to be running.

Works great if i run simple shell commands os.system("ls -l") and so on.

Works great if I run the same as a normal python script, not as a web server.

Tried starting some other services also not working.
I tried with try catch, catch part is not getting executed.
The browser is in connecting/receiving state forever.

Any help on this please ?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is stuck because os.system block until the command is finished. So if the `nginx` command is not going to background, the process will not end, and your code will stuck.

An alternative is to use [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module:

```
from subprocess import Popen

# start a new command
cmd = Popen("/home/.../nginx", shell=True)

# you can regulary check if the command is still running with:
cmd.poll()
if cmd.returncode is None:
    print "process is still running !"
else:
    print "process exited with code %d" % cmd.returncode

# or even kill it
cmd.kill()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried still I am getting the same issue also tried with subprocess.call, having nginx &. When I make the call I see "process is still running !" but when I make the call again it doesn't show up and the call from browser just hangs up. No response goes to the browser.
As a normal python program it works. 
There is this strange thing happening when I kill my python server

Comment: BASEHTTP 
netstat -lnp  | grep 8008
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11007/python

NGINX Running under pid  11009
netstat -lnp | grep 11009
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8085                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11009/    

AFTER KILLING BASEHTTP 
kill 11007

NOW UNDER 11009 there are two ports listening
netstat -lnp | grep 11009
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8008                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11009/    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:8085                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      11009/

Comment: Is python is executed by nginx itself ?

Comment: The python web server servers a page. When a button is clicked nginx is started as child of python_web_server.
But just found that the nginx process is <defunct>.
I ve tried os.system("./nginx"), Popen, subprocess.call.